# Moment generating Function Problem

Tags: generating-functions

My task is to find a fitting probability distribution function.

For $X$, the moment generating function is given as 
$$mx(s) = \left(\frac{1-p}{1-pe^s}\right)^2$$

$p\in(0,1)$ is a parameter.

I don't know where to start.

Comment: This moment generating function is wrong since $mx(0)=E${$1$}$=(1-p)^2\neq 1$

Comment: Yes, thats my problem... I don't know what to do with the parameter p. I've learned that the kth derivative of mx(s) is the kth moment

Comment: Are my edits good?

Comment: Well! The same problem still persists....

Comment: Sorry but could you explain? This formula was given in a lecture

Comment: Sure! The moment generating function has been defined as $m_X(s)=E(e^{sx})=\int e^{sx}f_X(x)dx$. Substituting $s=0$ leads us to $m_X(0)=E(1)=\int f_X(x)dx=1$. A similar argument is true for discrete case.

Comment: ok after I asked my prof he told me that the function must look like this.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to find the distribution that belongs to the generating function $$M_U(s)=\frac{1-p}{1-pe^s} $$
When $s$ is chosen such that $|pe^s|<1$, we can write:
$$M_U(s)=(1-p) \sum_{k=0}^\infty (pe^s) ^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{sk}p^k(1-p)$$
But that is just the one for geometric distribution. Since MGF is unique we can conclude  $U\sim \operatorname{Geo}((1-p))$ with probability mass function:
$$f_U(k)=p^k(1-p)\ \ \ \ \  k=0,1,2,...$$
Notice that some define the geometric distribution in another way, but that is not a problem.

The original $M_X(s)$ is just the moment generating function of $U+U'$ with $U$ and $U'$ i.i.d.

Such distribution has a name, namely negative binomial distribution. I think from here you can pick the robe to finish it, right?